# Not able to login into Stack Overflow with google open Id in Firefox 16

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, login, firefox

I am not able to login to Stack Overflow with my Gmail account on Firefox 16. But I can do the same with the latest Chrome. Whats is happening? any bug?

Comment: do you getting any error?

Comment: No I am not getting any error. It just redirects me back to the page which I was in before login. But I dont see myself as logged in.

Comment: I've just had to re-install Chrome to add my comment to this. I get exactly the same problem, Firefox redirects as it says you are logged in , but then you are not logged in. Using Google OpenID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your cookies and logging in again. It worked for me with Firefox 21.0. If it does not work for you, see 0__'s answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177567/unable-to-login-with-firefox).