# Unable to login with firefox

Tags: bug, login, firefox

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked, but I cannot find a solution. I use firefox allot more than chrome and I can't log into any stack website (including stack exchange) with firefox. I get no error in the developer console (not sure if I'm supposed to) and it is really frustrating. Is there any fix to this.

What keeps happening is my page just refreshes again and again and again and it never ends.

Comment: Not really related, nevertheless worth a read: http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: Did you clear your cookies?

Comment: http://news.bbc.co.uk/today/hi/today/newsid_9644000/9644002.stm

Comment: Yes, I did clear my cookies.

Comment: @Sklivvz You guys are so judgmental :c The way I type is irrelevant to the question -_-

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie I am just pretending :-)

Comment: This is The Internet though. If someone published the cure for cancer online but misplaced an apostrophe then that's what would get all the attention.

Comment: So is there any solution? I see the same problem after I accidentally cleared my browsing history in Firefox 20 OS X. Strangely I can use other stackexchange site, somehow. The buttons would respond for meta.stackoverflow, but not for the main site. I get this error in the console: "[13:07:44.468] SecurityError: The operation is insecure. @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/openid-jquery.js?v=xxx:9" what the heck is this?

Answer (score 3):

I cleared this problem with the following:

- go to menu "options", then the privacy tab
- select "Use custom settings for history"
- select "Show Cookies"
- Search for and delete all the cookies for "stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem, I don't know if it is the same. I accidentally flushed my browser history, which meant that all cookie permission settings were gone. I am using manual confirmation of cookies.

It turned out that when going to `stackoverflow.com`, Firefox was *not asking if I want to accept cookies*. Normally it would do so at the time the site tries to set its first cookie.

I double checked with the preferences, stackoverflow was not black listed.

The solution oddly was to manually add stackoverflow.com -> allow for session to the cookie preferences. Then I refreshed the site, and the login buttons would respond again.