# Trouble Logging in on Firefox

Tags: support, login

I'm having trouble logging into StackExchange (not StackOverflow) using the Firefox browser.  Internet Explorer works OK.

Here's what happenns with Firefox.  When I go to the main SE entry page, it shows me the log in option at the top, instead of my user name.  When I click on this,  I get a page that says that I've been logged back in and to click here to refresh the page.  I do that, and it takes me back to the log in screen.

I've seen some very similar questions in here, but none of the answers help me.  Is this some sort of generic problem with Firefox?  Should I be asking over in Super User instead of here?

Comment: I would guess Firefox extension is causing those problems.

Comment: Does this help: [Unable to login with firefox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177567)?